# React: What Controls Value of this.props.loading?

Tags: reactjs

I have several React containers and components running perfectly, but I'm still studying and learning React.  When my function componentDidMount runs in a new component I'm working on, it appears that all the data my component needs is available to the component, but `this.props.loading` is set to `true`;

```
componentDidMount() {
    const a = 100; //breakpoint here
    if (this.props.loading === false){
        const {myDataID} = this.props;
        this.fromID = Meteor.userId();
        this.toID = myDataID;

        this.subscribe(fromID, toID);
    }
}
```

What controls the value in `this.props.loading`? Will componentDidMount run again if `this.props.loading` is set to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prop`, `this.props.loading` is set by the parent component. If you feel your component has all the necessary data to perform a render you **don't** need to check if `this.props.loading` is `true` or `false`. It's a good practice to have this check because some times due to network errors you might not get the data you needed. This will break your code.

`componentDidMount` will only be called once after the render function is done

> Invoked once, both on the client and server, immediately before the initial rendering occurs. If you call setState within this method, render() will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.

But, when you change the `loading` prop in the parent, `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called with the `nexProp`, which is your change.

For more info, [check here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods)

Answer (score 1):

> What controls the value in `this.props.loading`?

The component that is rendering that component. I.e. if this `componentDidMount` method is in a component `Bar`, and in `Foo`'s `render` method:

```
render() {
   return <Bar loading={computeLoadingState()} />
}
```

Every time `Foo` is rerendered, `Bar` is potentially passed new value for `loading`.

> Will `componentDidMount` run again if `this.props.loading` is set to false?

No. The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) says:

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs.

[Other methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) however are invoked whenever props change.